# Pandoc and NodeJS: How do I get result as a file blob?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pandoc

I'm trying to convert some HTML markup into a PDF in a NodeJS web application using pandoc. I've pandoc installed on the server where my app is running. I'm using [node-pandoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pandoc) to try and achieve this. This is the code I'm using:

```
return new Promise<string> ((resolve, reject) => {
  nodePandoc(content, '-f html -t pdf', (error, result) => {
    resolve(result);
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
});
```

From node-pandoc's docs, I'm supposed to get the result of the conversion on the console if I omit the `-o` flag as I've done here. What I'm trying to do is get the result and convert it into a file blob so I can send to my client side. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error says something like `Unknown writer: pdf`, right?

> I'm supposed to get the result of the conversion on the console if I omit the `-o` flag

That's actually only possible for non-binary output formats. So it's not possible for PDF. You need to use `-o out.pdf`. Then use node's `fs` to read that file again and send the binary to the client, or move it to some static file server.

Btw. You also need to install LaTeX. See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This helps.